# C structure code compiling but not running

Tags: c, structure

I learnt (self-learning) the basics of structure in C today and wrote this simple code. it is compiling without any error. I know that successful compilation is no guarantee for a bug-free software. While execution, it scans the inputs for two structure variables only and gives erroneous display. for the sake of simplicity I chose a char to store the book name. I am not able to figure out the bug here. could you find one?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct book
    {   char name;
        float price;
        int pages;
    };

    struct book b[3];

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        printf("\nEnter name, price and pages ");
        scanf("%c %f %i", &b[i].name, &b[i].price, &b[i].pages);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        printf("\n%c %f %i",b[i].name, b[i].price, b[i].pages);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your input? And what's your erroneous output?

Comment: Just because you get no errors when compiling, that doesn't mean your program will actually do what you want. This is normally called a *bug*.

Comment: @GregHewgill I am aware of the fact that compilation is no guarantee  for bug-free software. I was interested in knowing the bug in the above mentioned code, which is not so apparent. if you could see a bug, kindly mention it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove "extra" input by adding `while((ch=getchar())!='\n');` ( to flush the input buffer) (Please declare the `char ch;`):

```
for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
   printf("\nEnter name, price and pages ");
   scanf("%c %f %i",&b[i].name,&b[i].price, &b[i].pages);
   while((ch=getchar())!='\n'); //eat the chars
 }
```

Tutorial/posts:

1. ["Flushing" the input stream](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/90228/flushing-the-input-stream)
2. [How to Get User Input from console -- safely.](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/268836/how-to-get-user-input-from-console-safely)

Comment: awesome.. it worked!!! thanks a lot.. could you discuss a bit more, what exactly was going wrong. ( for extending my learning from this problem)

Comment: @Saurabh - Glad you got it working. The solution is "Flushing" the input stream/buffer.

Comment: @Saurabh - the scanf() only reads from stdin (the keyboard) until it has matched everything in the format string (a character, a space, a floating point number, a space, then an integer in your case). That leaves the carriage return / line-feed floating in the input buffer, and AVD's while() loop eats data until that has also been received: then you're ready for the next entry.